# How to remove active class in active submenu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

```html
<li id="menu-item-332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-332">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Pages</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-329 current_page_item menu-item-333">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/our-team/" aria-current="page" class="nav-link active">
                Team
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-336" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-336">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/team-single/">
                Team Single
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-463">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/404">
                Error 404
            </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am currently active in page **Team**. And team is a submenu. I need an active class to only parent menu, not to the submenu. If I open a sub menu it adds `nav-link active` class to parent menu

```html
<li id="menu-item-332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-332">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Pages</a>
</li>
```

but it also adds to the submenu

```html
<li id="menu-item-333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-329 current_page_item menu-item-333">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/our-team/" aria-current="page" class="nav-link active">
        Team
    </a>
</li>
```

how can I remove the `nav-link active` class from submenu? Here is my functions.php file:

```php
function add_class_to_href( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( in_array('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) {
        $classes['class'] = 'nav-link active';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_href', 10, 2 );

function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) || in_array('current-menu-ancestor', $item->classes) ){
        $classes['class'] = 'nav-link active';
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hope help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52087/remove-class-sub-menu-from-wordpress-drop-down-menu

Comment: I checked it already bro . It is removing class from parent menu also . I want to remove only from sub menu . Please help me . Thanks in advance